# Convert date time format ASP.net MVC @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask if how can I convert a date format of like "Dec 05, 2019" to this line? `@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) Now, item.created_d)` from auto crud function from mvc controller

Thank you

Comment: DateTime Formating in C# is done like so DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy"). Would be better to do this in the controller. But should work either way

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to convert it from controller side. If you still want to convert it in razor then you can create [Custom HTML Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).